# Rendering action with URL parameter in Rails Controlller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters, render, validationerror

In my scenario I have a form at a URL

`localhost:3000/products/new?product_type='abc'`

When I fill the form and hit save, due to validation error it runs the block of rails as follows:

```
format.html {
  render :new,
  status: :unprocessable_entity
}
```

and it renders the browser to `localhost:3000/products/new`

But in my case I want to render to the same page where I started along with the data user has filled in the `Product Form`..

What could be the best possible solution so user should stay on the previous page along with the data and params in url.

as

`localhost:3000/products/new?product_type='abc'`

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm confused. You say that `render(:new, status: :unprocessable_entity)` causes a redirect?

Comment: Oh @JaredBeck my bad, it actually renders, not redirect to the action.

Answer (score 0):

That's very simple If you want to stay in page after any form submission you have to use **[Rails "Ajax helpers"](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html)**

```
<%= form_with(@product, remote: true) do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Here you can see I pass **`remote: true`** as additional params that will send your form as Ajax request instead for refresh current form page.

#### Return Json as error response:

```
format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
```

You can also create a page with **page.js.erb** extension to handle your javascript code.